# Plus minus in hackerrank

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C and I am doing problems in hackerrank and I came across a problem called "plus minus" where the expected output in the problem is not obtained.

Where I got the confusion in floating datatypes in calculation.  Here is the problem.  We have to give array of numbers contains positive,negative and zero values and input and output should be as follows.

```
6
-4 3 -9 0 4 1
```

Sample Output

```
0.500000
0.333333
0.166667
```

There are 3  positive numbers, 2 negative numbers, and 1 zero in the array. 
The proportions of occurrence are positive: 3/6=0.50000, negative:2/6 =0.33333 and zeros:1/6=0.166667 ..

Here is my code that not getting expected output.

```
int main()
{
    int n,i,p,q,r,a[50],pos,res,zer,neg;
    double posres,negres,zerres;

    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>0)
            ++p;
        else if(a[i]<0)
            ++q;
        else if(a[i]=0)
            ++r;
    }

    posres=p/n;
    negres=q/n;
    zerres=r/n;
    printf("%lf\n%lf\n%lf\n",posres,negres,zerres);
    return 0;
}
```

But my output is:

```
699317.000000
162833139.000000
0.000000
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: First you really should learn how to format you code so others and yourself can read it without breaking their eyes.

Comment: Sorry but your code is really unreadable. We also need the exact description of your problem. And input output pair on which it fails.

Comment: You did not initialize your variables you are incrementing.

Comment: You don't need the array (if `n` is bigger than 50 the array will be overrun). Just `scanf` into a temporary variable and update the counts. Also, integer division truncates. So if `p` is 1 and `n`  is 3, the line `posres=p/n` will set `posres` to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `a[i]=0`, which is assigning value `0` to `a[i]`, with `a[i]==0`, which is a comparison. And initialize `p`, `q`, and `r` to `0` before the loop. Otherwise you'll get undefined behaviour, e.g. the garbage you see.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    double zero_count = 0;
    double pos_count = 0;
    double neg_count = 0;
    double num = 0;


    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &num);

        if(num > 0) {
            ++pos_count;
        } else if(num < 0) {
            ++neg_count;
        } else if(num == 0) {
            ++zero_count;
        }
    }

    printf("%lf\n%lf\n%lf\n",(pos_count/n), (neg_count/n), (zero_count/n));
    return 0;
}
```

1. Even if there is only one line of code inside a loop, use braces to wrap the loop. You will save yourself a lot of headache when dealing with massive pieces of code.
2. Insert spaces between variables and syntactical borders. Compilers will understand what you have written, humans find it hard to read.